# Do photons influence charged particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, photons, charge

As a neutrally charged particle, a photon shouldn't interact electrically with another charged particle. However, since photons are electromagnetic waves, they should interact with charged particles, both electrically and magnetically.

Is this because the average in time of the electric and magnetic fields is zero?

(physics student)

Answer (score -2):

No, as you also said that **photons** are **neutral particles** due to this property, **no charge** will be interact with ***Photons*** because the **rest mass** and **charge** is **zero** and also they don't have any **magnetic poles**.